# Date wrong in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, google-chrome, datetime

Why when I create without space in javascript console is to the yesterday date at 9:00PM, but when I write with a space in the end the date and hour is ok?

```js
new Date('2021-07-20')
```

Wrong: Mon Jul 19 2021 21:00:00

---

```js
new Date('2021-07-20 ')
```

Correct: Tue Jul 20 2021 00:00:00

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What environment are you using here? Browser? What kind?

Comment: In Chrome terminal and ReactJS.

Comment: Edit your question and use the snippet function with  console.log. In Firefox the date with space will return an error.

Comment: I can see difference in Node.js and Chrome, but see [Date() constructor -Timestamp string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#timestamp_string): "Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2021-07-20` is a valid [ISO time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It gets parsed as 20th July 2021 at midnight UCT. It then gets converted to local time for you which (in Porto Alegre) is three hours earlier.

`2021-07-20`  is not a valid ISO time, so it hits your JS engine's implementation-specific parser for non-standard date formats.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use , between them like:
const d = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30);
And remember JavaScript counts months and days from 0 to 11 just like indexes.